# How to use composite key as a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have two tables in my database.

This is the schema...

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt (
ReceiptID VARCHAR(50),
ProductNo SMALLINT,
ProductBarcode SMALLINT,
FOREIGN KEY (productNo, productBarcode) REFERENCES Receipt(productNo, productBarcode),
PRIMARY KEY (receiptID)
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
ProductNo SMALLINT,
ProductBarcode SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (productNo, productBarcode)
);
```

I am using MySQL and I need some help using the composite key.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating a composite key in mysql database is

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (col_1,col_2,col_3)
```

For you situation:

-- creating constraint while creating the table----

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt 
(
ReceiptID VARCHAR(50),
ProductNo SMALLINT,
ProductBarcode SMALLINT,

PRIMARY KEY (receiptID),
INDEX (productNo, productBarcode)

FOREIGN KEY (productNo, productBarcode) 
REFERENCES Receipt(productNo, productBarcode)
);
```

-- Adding constraint to already existing table----
    ALTER TABLE Receipt
    ADD [constraint [constraint_name]]
    FOREIGN KEY (productNo, productBarcode) 
    REFERENCES Receipt(productNo, productBarcode)

Comment: so in this case, how do I use it as a foreign key?

Comment: On which table and which column name you want a foreign key ?

Comment: I want the foreign key in the receipt table